# Using HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile vs HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile

Tags: html, css, web-applications, google-apps-script

I have a problem with my Google Apps Script. I need a responsive design app with the right title in the tab (usually declared by the  tag).

Using HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile makes it possible to add the meta tag which makes responsive design possible:

```
     var template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index'); 
template.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
```

However, this makes it impossible to use functions like setTitle(). These functions are possible with 
HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile:

```
 var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Also, using createTemplateFromFile makes the following possible in the HTML:

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
```

When trying this with createHtmlOuputFromFile the browser returns an error.

I need to use createHtmlOutputFromFile for the responsive design, so can anyone help me with setTitle() etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Realizing_common_layouts_using_CSS_Grid_Layout) and flex box? I've used it on several standalone apps with much success. This HTML and CSS is my favourite point of reference

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <header class="main-head">The header</header>
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Nav 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <article class="content">
            <h1>Main article area</h1>
            <p>In this layout, we display the areas in source order for any screen less that 500 pixels wide. We go to a two column layout, and then to a three column layout by redefining the grid, and the placement of items on the grid.</p>
        </article> 
        <aside class="side">Sidebar</aside>
        <div class="ad">Advertising</div>
        <footer class="main-footer">The footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

    .wrapper {
        max-width: 1024px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font: 1.2em Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .wrapper > * {
        border: 2px solid #f08c00;
        background-color: #ffec99;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
.main-head {
  grid-area: header;
}
.content {
  grid-area: content;
}
.main-nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}
.side {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}
.ad {
  grid-area: ad;
}
.main-footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "nav"
    "content"
    "sidebar"
    "ad"
    "footer";
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header  header"
      "nav     nav"
      "sidebar content"
      "ad      footer";
  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header header  header"
      "nav    content sidebar"
      "nav    content ad"
      "footer footer  footer"
   }
   nav ul {
     flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

Comment: Google apps script does not allow these tags. I think it's because the app is run within an iframe

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer. I didn't know about the tags.

Answer (score 0):

late answer, but You can do this,

```
var template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
    template.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');

    return template.asTemplate().evaluate()
               .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
               .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```